# Blocked a frame with origin "https://dev.*******" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, cors, cypress

I am getting errors whenever I run this code to load an iframe on cypress.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://dev.expensa.me" from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

```js
cy.frameLoaded('#connect__iframe')    
cy.iframe('#connect__iframe')
  .find('button_Continue')
  .click()
```

Comment: Add to the question a screenshot of the error you are getting.

Comment: Hello @AlapanDas, I have added the message I am getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [the Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Cross-origin-iframes):

> If your site embeds an `<iframe>` that is a cross-origin frame,
> Cypress will not be able to automate or communicate with this
> `<iframe>`.
>
> ### Examples of uses for cross-origin iframes
>
> - Embedding a Vimeo or YouTube video.
> - Displaying a credit card form from Stripe or Braintree.
> - Displaying an embedded login form from Auth0.
> - Showing comments from Disqus.
>
> It's actually possible for Cypress to accommodate these situations the
> same way Selenium does, but you will never have native access to these
> iframes from inside of Cypress.
>
> As a workaround, you may be able to use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to
> directly communicate with these iframes and control them (if the 3rd
> party iframe supports it).
>
> Other than that, you'll have to wait for us to implement APIs to
> support this (check our [open issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136)), or you can [disable web
> security](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Disabling-Web-Security).